# How can I update protobuf file for client when server changed

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm new in microservices ecosystem and I've just start study about gRPC. But I have a problem when I try to understand gRPC and Protobuf workflow.

First, I have a server and a client talk to each other via gRPC with NodeJS. Then I got a problem with my server so I have to fix it. But unfortunately, I have to change protobuf file too because I realize that error come from my gRPC Service.

So, for now I'm change protobuf file in both client and server manually. But I want to change(sync) proto file in client automatically(that's microservices, right?).

Please show me your method to make it auto! :(

Comment: I guess this is a question about how to manage dependencies so that both the client and the server share the same copy of the proto file. There are lots of possible answers to that question. However, keep in mind that _you don't need to update the client_ unless the client needs to use a new field that you added. Protobuf is designed so that you can add new fields without updating old programs unless they need to use the new field -- it's backwards-compatible.

Comment: I have to build a system that delivery services so I need it dynamic. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to automate this by extracting out your .proto file in a separate project and build a pipeline which will generate stub code and publish it to a common place. And then you can use that by adding it as a dependency to your client and server.

But as @Kenton said, you don't have to update your .proto file at the client for all the changes, it's backward compatible by default.